# nodemcu Lua sqr function

Tags: math, lua, nodemcu, sqr

-I want to buy nodemcu board and apply the Pythagora's Theorem but I dont know if sqr function exists on nodemcu lua interpreter ?

I googled on web and I found few doc with sqr() but on official Faq math funtions are omitted:

-The debug and math libraries have also been omitted to reduce the runtime footprint.-
(https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/lua-developer-faq/.)

Does it exist?
Thanks so much

Comment: Does the sqr function exist ? I want to use that function on nodemcu board , Thanks

Comment: `sqr` (=square) or `sqrt` =(square root)?

Comment: Hi , I mean sqrt :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont know if sqr function exists on nodemcu lua interpreter ?

Not it is not available. You may want to subscribe to https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1280.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use the wifi capabilities, you could also use a RESTful service to let an external server do your SQRT() calculations and then use the result you receive . You can search for the "math" tag on Programmableweb, but i have linked you the wolfram Alpha API , which can do more than just math.
http://www.programmableweb.com/api/wolfram-alpha